# how to add a video into html

Tags: html, video

I want to add a video into my html code and it should be accessible at least from IE ,firfox and chrome browsers.

The extension of the video is .vob

I have used this code

```
<object data="../Video/VTS_01_1.vob" height="200" width="200"></object>
```

But I can't see nothing on the screen juste a square with 200 height and 200 width

Comment: Why are you not using the HTML 5 [video](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/) element?

Comment: If you plan on using HTML5, take a look at the video tag: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/video. Take note of the syntax and the MIME types for video accepted.

Comment: @poplex - please read [w3fools](http://w3fools.com) before next recommended w3schools

Comment: @Oded. Will do, sorry. Comment amended.

Comment: @merp — The OP isn't trying to link to third party video content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use [the `<video>` element](http://html5doctor.com/the-video-element/)
- Use a file format supported by browsers. VOB is not such a format. MP4 and WebM are good choices for different browsers, you should use both
- Consider using a library that provides Flash et al fallbacks for old browsers. Examples include [video.js](http://videojs.com/) and [video for everybody](http://camendesign.co.uk/code/video_for_everybody)

Answer (score 0):

Sample Code:

```
<video width="640" height="360" src="/demo/google_main.mp4?2" autobuffer>
    <div class="fallback">
        <p>................</p>
    </div>
</video>
```

wrapped up the same old `<object>` and `<embed>` tags with the new  tag .

More info about [video](http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_video_tag.cfm) tag